# CI not loading library

Tags: codeigniter

Here's my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        redirect('user/login');
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation', '', 'fv');
        var_dump($this);
        $this->fv->set_rules('nick_name', 'Nick Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|min_length[4]');
        $this->fv->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
    }
}
?>
```

I was basically writing a login controller. In the login function, after this I load the view, etc. But up till here, I am getting the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: User::$fv
Filename: controllers/user.php
Line Number: 23
```

I have commented out everything else in the controller effectively to what I have pasted above. I don't get where the problem is. Thanks.

[EDIT]

On var dumping the $this object, I found an even more unusual thing. The object "fv" was not defined inside the $this object but rather under the $this->user_model object. So isset($this->fv) was returning false and isset($this->user_model->fv) was returning true. And yes I tried $this->load->library('form_validation') instead of naming it "fv", results remained the same.

Comment: this one  `$this->fv->set_rules('nick_name', 'Nick Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|min_length[4]');`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller name should named as user.php & it should located inside the controllers folder.

Try CI recommended coding styles,  such as,

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules(); etc..

Comment: his user.php controller is fine and running, it's the form_validation.php that is the issue.